# Send email from Kibana Canvas

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert, kibana-7

I am using free ELK Stack 7.3.2 for process monitoring.
Using Kibana Canvas for visualization of my uptime messaging.
Here are the sample messages:

> {"processName":"SM1","processType":"serviceManager","status":"DOWN","update":"2h14m","hostname":"devvm20"}
>
> {"processName":"SM2","processType":"serviceManager","status":"UP","update":"2h14m","hostname":"devvm20"}

The processName is my unique key.

I am looking for a way to send an email if my message was late or slow within 2 minutes.

The ELK Stack Watchers would help out but they are a part of the X-Pack and also subscription based.

How can use ElastAlert instead?